# A simple question on groups and quotient spaces.

Tags: group-theory

Consider a group and its subgroup: 
$$\,K\,<\,G\,\;.$$ 
An element $g\in G$ generates a bijection of $\,G\,$ onto itself,
 \begin{eqnarray}
 \hat{\cal{L}}_g\;\colon\quad G\longrightarrow G\;,\qquad
  x\;\longrightarrow\;\hat{
  \cal
  {L}}_g\,x\;=\;g\;x\;\,,
 \end{eqnarray}
 and a bijection of the coset space onto itself,
 \begin{eqnarray}
 \hat{L}_g\;\colon\quad G/K\longrightarrow G/K\;,\qquad
 x\,K\;\longrightarrow\;\hat{L}_g\,(x\,K)\;=\;g\;x\;K\;\,.
 \end{eqnarray}

The set of operators $\,{\mathtt{L}}\,=\,\{\,\hat{\mathit{L}}_g\;\big{|}\;g\in G\,\}\,$ can be interpreted as a map
 \begin{eqnarray}
 {\mathtt{L}}\,:\quad G \longrightarrow \operatorname{Aut_{set}}(G/K)\,\;,
  \end{eqnarray}
 where $\,\operatorname{Aut_{set}}(G/K)\,$ denotes the set of all bijections of $\,G/K\,$ onto itself.

Is this map into or onto?

In other words, can any bijection of $\,G/K\,$ onto itself be written as $\,L_g\,$, with $\,g\in G\,$?

Comment: There are two extreme cases here, $K = \{ e \}$ and $K = G$. The first case shows that $L$ is not surjective in general and the second case shows that $L$ is not injective in general either.

Comment: If $K=\{e\}$ then $G/K$ coincides with $G$. Accordingly, the left translation on the coset space coincides with a corresponding left translation on the group:
$$L_g = {\cal L}_g\,\;. $$

Comment: Yes. And there are $|G|$ of these maps, while there are $|G|!$ maps from $G$ to itself.

Comment: If $K=\{e\}$ then $G/K$ coincides with $G$. Accordingly, the left translation on the coset space coincides with a corresponding left translation on the group:
$$L_g = {\cal L}_g\,\;. $$
You say that the so-obtained map  $G\longrightarrow$ Aut$_{set}(G/K)$ is not surjective. Thereby you imply that there exist bijections of $G/K$ (in our case, bijections of $G$) which are not $\cal{L}_g$. What kind of bijections are these? Is this, say, $g\longrightarrow g^{-1}~$ ?

Comment: The bijections are not any particular kind. Almost all bijections of $G$ are not left translations: for example, in general the bijection which simply exchanges two elements of $G$.